# mysql: import schema without losing data

Tags: mysql, import, mysql-workbench

I have a database of about 15 tables which I restructured a bit (changed to innoDB, created Foreign Keys etc) using MySQL Workbench. I can extract the schema in sql format from the EER diagram but how can I import it in mySQL without losing my data?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword dbname < schema.sql
```

But don't forget about creating database `dbname` and about grants for user `user`.

Comment: this won't work if you have ```DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <table>``` in your schema.sql, you first need to make sure that the drop table statement is not present in your schema.sql, but running:

```mysql -uuser -ppassword dbname < schema.sql```

might raise an error like: ```ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line <num>: Table <table> already exists```